# add_rewrite_rule not working

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, api

I'm trying to do some url rewriting. I've picked this example right off the wordpress wiki [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule):

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?foo=bar','top');
```

The wiki page says:

> This example would match a requested URL like this: 
>   example.com/nutrition/milkshakes/strawberry/ ...and interpret it to
>   actually mean...
>   example.com/index.php?page_id=12&food=milkshake&variety=strawberry

(I've simplified it to redirect to index.php?foo=bar ). However, I'm still getting a 404 error when I try to visit `http://localhost/myblog/nutrition/milkshakes/strawberry/`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your actual, not simplified rewrite rule? you have to load a WordPress object- a page, a post, an archive, etc.. You can't just set arbitrary non-existent query vars.

Comment: @Milo My line for setting the url is exactly as i gave, `index.php?foo=bar`

Comment: did you add the rule on the init action? have you flushed rewrite rules by visiting the permalinks settings page?